pgfplots: issues shading inequalities in two variables
I am striving to reproduce the following Mathematica graphic (done using RegionPlot) in tikz using pgfplots

Here is the MWE of what I tried:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
    view={0}{90},          % 2D top-down view
    samples=100,           % Number of samples for accuracy
    domain=-1.4:0.2,       % x-domain
    y domain=-0.6:0.6,     % y-domain
    restrict z to domain=-inf:1, % Restrict z-values
    xmin=-1.4, xmax=0.2,   % Set x-limits
    ymin=-0.8, ymax=0.8,   % Set y-limits
    ]
    
    \addplot3 [surf, 
      shader=flat, % Use flat shading (uniform)
      fill=blue!50, % Uniform light blue color
      draw=none,     % Disable drawing surface boundaries
      mesh/rows=0,   % Disable row grid lines
      mesh/cols=0    % Disable column grid lines
      ]
    {
      ln((1+x)^2+y^2)+ln((1+(7*x)/2)^2+(49*y^2)/4)+ln((1+4*x)^2+16*y^2) 
    };
    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

produces

which surprises me because I thought
  draw=none,     % Disable drawing surface boundaries
  mesh/rows=0,   % Disable row grid lines
  mesh/cols=0    % Disable column grid lines

would have disabled the mesh lines and shaded everything a uniform light blue, but neither of these are happening.
Any advice on how I can resolve these two issues?

Would you be interested by a solution using only TikZ?  It would need a bisection program to obtain the points of the level curve you are interested in.

I think at pgfplots you will need one of contour lua, contour filled or contour gnuplot. I get your curve nicely with the first one, but `I do not know how to fill. So I think you will need the last (gnuplot). Maybe I will open a thread my fill-problem.

@JohnD See here for a solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729205/46023

@cis If you want to post your link as an answer, I will accept it.
